# How to use a join on three tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, join

I want to use a double SQL join in Entity Framework code-first. I can do it with a SQL query but I can't translate it to C# entity code.

My SQL code is :

```
SELECT 
    CS.CustomerId, CS.CustomerName, SF.FactorId, SD.SaleDate
FROM 
    [dbo].[SaleFactors] SF
JOIN
    [dbo].[Customers] CS ON SF.CustomerId = CS.CustomerId
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         [FactorId], [SaleDate]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[SaleProducts]
     WHERE
         SaleDate >= 2016 AND SaleDate <= 2018) SD ON SD.FactorId = SF.FactorId
```

How can I do this using C#?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .Include(blog => blog.Owner)
        .ToList();
}
```

If you have a mapping and a DbContext defined to map your database tables you are good to go using the `.Include()` statements.
This code snippet and the official docs should kickstart you and your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    var result = context.SaleFactors
            .Where(x => x.SaleProducts.SaleDate >= 2016  &&x.SaleProducts.SaleDate <= 2018 )
            .Select(x => new
  {
     FactorId = x.FactorId ,
     CustomerId = x.Customers.CustomerId  ,
     CustomerName = x.Customers.CustomerName ,
     SaleDate = x.SaleProducts.SaleDate .

  }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
I solved it , it's my code :

```
var varGetSaleInformation = (from factor in oDatabaseContext.SaleFactors
    join sale in oDatabaseContext.SaleProducts
      on factor.FactorId equals sale.FactorId
        where sale.SaleDate >= 2016 && sale.SaleDate <= 2018
    join customer in oDatabaseContext.Customers
      on factor.CustomerId equals customer.CustomerId
        where factor.CustomerId.ToString().Contains(txtFactorId.Text)
    select new
    {
        customerId = customer.CustomerId,
        customerName = customer.CustomerName,
        factorId = factor.FactorId,
        factorPaymentType = factor.FactorPaymentType,
        saleDate = sale.SaleDate
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```